# not getting txn_id from paypal on success

Tags: php, paypal

It's working fine with IPN (getting all the variables), but after payment when user click on "Return to Merchant Store", here I didn't get anything..

I need the paypal variables, the same which I've got over IPN is there any another wayout?

However I can send the order id with success url like (success.php?orderid=5), but that's a last option.

I prefer, If the get the paypal transaction id (txn_id) on success.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you set IPN URL in your paypal account? Usually IPN URL handle all the logic not return URL. User maybe not even click on "Return to store" link.

Comment: yes IPN is working fine, i am getting all the parameters thorough IPN (notify_url), but not in return url(return)

Comment: For subscription variables, the transaction ID (txn_id) is only available for USD Payment and Multi-Currency Payment transaction types (txn_type).

As expected, PayPal will not send the txn_id to your IPN for the transaction type, subscr_cancel, and will only send txn_id if the transaction type is subscr_payment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can get all the Transaction details on redirect, same as IPN if we pass rm=2

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
```

See Paypal [Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0709B__id08A7CI030HS), and look for `rm` parameter.